# How to add trans values to symfony forms in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I'm trying to convert some form in my application over to symfony forms.  I have a birthday value that i want to have empty values for and the empty values should be 'month' 'day' 'year' respectively and would display the translated versions of those words depending on your local.  Right now i'm trying this with twig.

```
{{ form_row(form.birthday, {'empty_value':{ 'year':'title.year'|trans, 'month':'title.month'|trans, 'day':'title.day'|trans }}) }}
```

but that didn't work as i'm still seeing 'jan' '1' '1894' as my default values for the field.

this is how i defined it in the form:

```
->add(
    'birthday',
    'birthday',
    [
      'label' => false,
      'required' => true,
      'attr' => [
        'class' => 'date-fields'
      ]
    ]
)
```

is there a way to do this in twig or do i have to pass a translator to my form and generate the text in there?

Comment: Dirty way is to inject translate service to your `Type` and translate `empty_value` there not in Twig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try code below:

```
->add(
    'birthday',
    'birthday',
    [
        'label' => false,
        'required' => true,
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'date-fields'
        ],
        'empty_value' => 'your_translation_path' // for example title.year
    ]
)
```

And in your form's method setDefaultOptions you could add default translation domain, like that:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'translation_domain' => 'AcmeDemoBundle',
    ]);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yeah, this is basically the way to do it.  The translations in my project are set up slightly differently than the standard symfony way so i had to make some other changes, but this lead me down the right path.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy way to do this.
Just make a translation file named as `messages.en.xliff`
in this directory

```
YourProject
         |___app
              |___Resources
                         |___translations
                                       |___messages.en.xliff
```

and in `messages.en.xliff` just add this line

```
        <trans-unit id="Title">
            <source>Title</source>
            <target>标题</target>
        </trans-unit>
```

Check this one.Don't forgot to clear cache
No need to add trans in form.